# Understanding the ところ in 議論を呼ぶところ

Tags: grammar

> 目覚めは、唐突なものだった。
>
> 否、それが果てして一般的な『目覚め』に当たるのかどうかは議論を呼ぶ**ところ**ではあったのだけれど。
>
> とにかく、狂三は意識を取り戻した。即座に周囲の状況を確認する。

Source: Date a live, novel

Context: 狂三 had transformed her current consciousness to her past body with her power and just woke up.

As far as I know, the construction 「verb(る)+ところ」has three usages.

1. 電話が鳴った時、私は家に帰るところだった。(be about to do)
2. この字は赤で書くところだった。(should)
3. すんでのことで川に落ちてしまうところでした。(almost ... to some degree or result)

I’m not sure which usage apply to the ところ in the excerpt. Is it no.2? Or the ところ has other usages?

Comment: I don't think this ところ exactly falls under these usages, however. I think it's similar to how ところ is used in instances like 言いたいところだが (marking a situation). But I will leave this to someone who can answer more confidently. 果てして also feels odd to me. Typo?

Comment: I doubt #2 means "should", it's more like "place to write in red" or otherwise same as #3.

Answer (score 4):

議論を呼ぶところではあったのだけれど＝議論を呼ぶものではあったけれど＝議論を呼ぶが

この場合の「ところ」に強い意味はないと思います。

ところ＝こと、もの

というように事柄を表し、

「動詞（verb）＋ところ」＝名詞化（nominalization）
という使い方です。

日本語は名詞化するより動詞のままで書いたほうが表現としてはすっきりするので、文章を書く上で意味があるとすれば、古めかしさや仰々しさを表すときには有効かもしれません。

例
みんなの認めるところではあるが＝みんなの認めることだが＝みんな認めているが

悩むところではあるが＝悩むことではあるが＝悩むが