# Understanding 仕方ないところ

Tags: grammar

> 慣れない手つきで敬礼をした、共和国の紺青の軍服の白銀種の少年に、白々とした空気が先任であるシンたち五人の間に漂う。
>
> 事前に話は聞いていたとはいえ、共和国市民。反発を覚えるのは仕方ない**ところ**だろう。
>
> と、集められた仲間たちの白けた雰囲気を感じつつ、シンは口を開く。
>
> 「元は軍人じゃないな。──なぜ志願を？　敬語はいらない、こちらも似たようなものだ」 　 人間と無人機という、扱いの違いこそあれ。
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.4　─アンダー・プレッシャー─ 安里アサト

Is the bold ところ necessary there? Does the ところ mean "situation" in this context?

Comment: This question (of yours) seems related: [Understanding the ところ in 議論を呼ぶところ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86124/43676)